# Is there anyway to Embed youtube 360 video to Android

Tags: android, video, youtube, 360-virtual-reality

I want to live stream a 360 video to my android app.

The main function of the app is to watch live 360 videos.

I tried using the YouTube API, but it does not work as it doesn´t render the video. I tried using the Google VRVideoView from the cardboard API. But it seems it can´t parse YouTube URI.

Is there any way I can do this? Or any alternative platform that supports 360 video steaming on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Pan frame SDK to play 360 video in Android App. I have updated the complete source code in Github,
https://github.com/JayaprakashR-Zealot/360VR

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: It doesn't support youtube, right? So if I wanted to Live stream something I would have to create my own server

Comment: If you have to use YouTube 360 Videos, you should rely on YouTube API only. If you have your own 360 videos, you can use Pan frame SDK.